# Hide the scroll-bar when expansion panel is collapsed

Tags: html, css

The problem I have is that the scroll-bar is showing when the expansion panel is collapsed. It's fine when it's expanded:
[Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omngd.png)
[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNBOv.png)

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="panel">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>HH:MM:SS</mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>Foo</mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

```
.panel {
max-height: 1500px;
width: 1000px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

It's fine when it's expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `overflow: hidden`, not `overflow: auto`.

Comment: I want to have an option to scroll if the message is too big.

Comment: Then, I think the best way to approach this is to use `overflow: auto` but make sure that the outer div is larger than the inner div when the text is short. Currently, I assume that either `mat-expansion-panel-header`,`mat-panel-title` or `mat-panel-description` is taller than `mat-expansion-panel`. Check with the elements inspector.